# Symfony access_control regex with GET parameter

Tags: php, regex, symfony, symfony-3.2, api-platform.com

I'm trying to catch an url with **GET** parameters like `/foo/bar?foobar=123` in the Symfony **access_control** (app/config/security.yml) and i'm unable to find a correct rule. Here are a few of my attempts:

`- { path: ^/foo/bar\?foobar=[0-9]+, roles: [ ROLE_USER ], methods: [ GET ] }
- { path: ^/foo/bar(\?)([^=]+)\=[0-9]+, roles: [ ROLE_USER ], methods: [ GET ] }
- { path: ^/foo/bar.+=[0-9]+, roles: [ ROLE_USER ], methods: [ GET ] }`

I'm out of ideas ... all other standard **access_control** rules are perfectly working, so my security settings are principally working (Symfony 3.2)

Any help would be awesome - i was not able to find any regex **GET** parameter relevant **access_control** rule examples ...

Greetings!
Niklas

Comment: im assuming that you are talking about `config.yml` you can add it to your questions. In my app i have this values: `- { path: .*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }` why do you need regex GET parameter for the rule o f access_control ?

Comment: "nothing works" - please be more specific.

Comment: `foobar=123` - since this is not part of route, but query parameter, you should match route `/foo/bar` and validate value and existense of `foobar` parameter within controller action.

If you can't find documentation for these regexp, why would you think that your colleagues will?

Comment: I edited my post with more example rules, and: all access_controls rules are located in the security.yml, which is mentioned and recommended by the Symfony docs . Why i need to catch GET parameters: The api is structured by entities, /foo/bar returns all bars, and /foo/bar?foobar=123 returns a specific entity with the given search conditions, so i want to handle all possibly scenarios with access_control (which generally works perfect!), so i think it's a bit weird not to find anything about this topic. My hope is to find anybody which had the same problem and solved it ...

Comment: To check the query parameter in the controller is a possible and neat solution, but my goal is to bundle/concentrate all security related rules in one configuration file (security.yml)

Comment: Hum do you want to limit access to some resources by roles ? 
Please give us a real example that you are trying to achieve (not foo/bar :D) with explanation

Comment: Since i'm using API platform and it's entities, i'm using the given standard structure: `/api/users` to get alls Users, `/api/users?countryCode=DE` to get all Users with countryCode `DE`. I have a few scenarios where i need to allow/disallow different search types. The **access_control** is imho the best and shortest way to handle those rules.